# How to do conditional validation based on a field outside of object in Joi validator

Tags: validation, joi

I have a validation schema that looks like the following:

```
const createdJobOpportunitySchema = Joi.object({
        countryWhereTheEmploymentHeld: Joi.string().valid('Local', 'Forign').required(),
        employerAddress: Joi.object({
            region: Joi.when('countryWhereTheEmploymentHeld', {
                is: Joi.string().valid('Local'),
                then: Joi.string().required(),
            }),
            zone: Joi.string().custom(mongoObjectIdValidator, 'Region Validator'),
            district: Joi.string().custom(mongoObjectIdValidator, 'Region Validator'),
        })
    });
```

So what I want to do is validate the 'region' based on the value of 'countryWhereTheEmploymentHeld'. If the value of 'countryWhereTheEmploymentHeld' is 'Local' then I want the region to be required(). Otherwise I don't want it to be required(). I can I be able to do that in Joi validator.

Answer (score 0):

Your `employerAddress` object is optional, which means, your `when` validation only works when you send the `employerAddress` object. To force the `employerAddress` to be required along side with the `employerAddress.region` you must place your `.when` outside the object:

```
Joi.object({
  countryWhereTheEmploymentHeld: Joi.string().valid('Local', 'Forign').required(),
  employerAddress: Joi.object({
    region: Joi.string()
  }),
  zone: Joi.string(),
  district: Joi.string()
}).when(Joi.object({ countryWhereTheEmploymentHeld: Joi.valid('Local') }).unknown(), {
   then: Joi.object({ 
     employerAddress: Joi.object({
       region: Joi.required()
     }).required() 
   })
})
```